# android 4.4.4(kitkat) ImageView Z-index

Tags: java, android, z-index

I'm trying to make my second ImageView displayed above the other twos, I used the  `ScaleX` and `ScaleY` methods,but unfortunately,neither `SetZ` or `setElavation` exists on android 4.4.4.....

Using `bringToFront()` doesn't give good results..It places the picture  the most left side

[image]

This is my code:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#aaaaaa"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"

            android:src="@drawable/wallpaper14"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/bigImage"
            android:src="@drawable/wallpaper16"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"

            android:src="@drawable/wallpaper17"/>
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Is there any alternative method to display the second Image above the others?

Answer (score 1):

On versions of Android that don't support elevation, the ordering or layering of views is controlled by which view is defined **last** in the XML file. You could therefore use a `ConstraintLayout` to host your images (rather than `LinearLayout`) and just make sure that your "second" image is the last child of the ConstraintLayout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout ...>

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/first" .../>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/third" .../>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/second" .../> // this one draws last, "on top"

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer,but I want the Image between to be displayed above....if I define the "second" image as the last child....it would not be placed on middle....agree?

Comment: ConstraintLayout lets you position your views in any way you want, regardless of the order in XML.